# Admin page for a small website

Tags: php, html

I've designed the basics of an admin page I'd like to use for a small website.  I'd like to know if I'm using the language properly.  Please rip apart the code and tell me what I could do better.

Admin page code, file called "index.php" (just the file name in my "netbeans" folder):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
    <title>Admin Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <table style="width:100%">
        <td valign="center" width="25%"><img src="BSQ_Logo.jpg" width="61"  height="36"></td>
        <td valign="center" align="center" width="15%"><b>Total Accounts:</b></td>
        <td valign="center" align="center" width="15%"><b>Logged On:</b></td>
        <td valign="center" align="center" width="15%"><b>Last Updated:</b></td>
        <td width="25%">
            <ul id="navlist">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
      </table>  
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <table id="labels" border="1" style="width:100%">
            <td width="20%">User</td>
            <td width="10%">ID</td>
            <td width="10%">Listings</td>
            <td width="10%">Connections</td>
            <td width="5%">Flags</td>
            <td width="10%">Days</td>
            <td width="25%">Email</b></td>
            <td width="10%">Suspend</td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
    include 'data_sheet.php';

    // call funciton form data_sheet.php to get array of data table
    $user_data = load_data($r);

    // array to line up the cells in the tables
    // each row under the collumn headings will be it's own table
    $cell_width = array('20%','10%','10%','10%', '5%', '10%','25%','10%');

    $listings_array = array(
        array('8343','7410', '1352'),
        array('6400','1432'),
        array(),
        array('3721','0185','4903','2132')
        );


    // funciton to that will return the a dropdown mennu
    function drop_menu ($listings)
    {
         $n_of_items = count($listings);
         echo "<form><select>
               <option>" . $n_of_items . "</option>\n";
         foreach ($listings as $key => $element)
         {
             echo "<option>" . $element . "</option>\n";
         }
         echo "</select></form>";
     }  // end of drop_menu function

     // function 'create_row creates a table for each row
     /*
      * aruments need to be:
      * --$prime coutner counts which row we are in
      * --$element i.e. array of info for each cell, which 
      *    should be the sub array from the database call
      * -- $cell_width from the cell width formatting araay
      * -- an array for each dropdown menue
      *    starting with 'listings' and 'connections'
      * -- $cell_width array - for formating each cell
      */
     function create_row ($prime_counter, $element, $listings, $connections, $cell_width)
     {
        // $sub_counter is for keeping track of which cell 
        // in the row is being dealth with
        $sub_counter = 0;
        // being the table for the account - one account/table per row
        echo <<<EOT
<br /><div><table border="1" style="width:100%">
EOT;
        // primary foreach loop goes through each 
        // account and lays out data in each cell;
        // data form a call to teh database
        foreach ($element as $subkey => $sub_element)
        {

            // begin cell in table
            echo <<<EOT
<td width=$cell_width[$sub_counter]>
EOT;
            // this determins what goes in the cell
            switch ($sub_counter) 
            {
                // case 2 is the listing information
                // need code here to putt the correct array
                // from the array of array of listings
                case 2:
                    // drop menu is to show a list of listings
                    // in the cell under the listings column
                    drop_menu($listings[$prime_counter]);
                    break;
                // default is the data from thte datbase call
                default:
                    echo $sub_element;
                    break;
            }
            // end cell in table
            echo "</td>";
            $sub_counter++;
        }// end foreach sub
        // close the table
        echo <<<EOT
</table></div>
EOT;
     } // end create row function

// ****begin display code for the tables under the column headings **********************

    /* foreach loop that puts data into the tables 
     * under the column headings
     * one table for each row
     * $user_data is the two dimentional array from the dataase
     */
    foreach ($user_data as $key => $element)
    {
        // need a database call based on the user data to get the
        // list of connections and listing for each user

        // $key to trigger the right arugments for
        // each row
        create_row($key, $element, $listings_array, 0, $cell_width);   
    }// end foreach main

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first glance, I don't see anything "wrong" with this. However, have you considered separating the logic from the view i.e. using the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern?

Comment: You are using tables as layout/design. Cascading StyleSheets (CSS) is for layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PHP Related Things

- Try not to mix HTML and PHP. PHP logic should come on top of the document, HTML below it. Within the HTML, there are just some minor `echo` and `if` statements and some loops. If you go a little bit more advanced, you should use something like the MVC pattern (like @karancan suggested).

#### Tips

- Take a look at PHPdocs. That's a common used way of documenting you PHP code.

### HTML/CSS Related Things

```
<td valign="center" width="25%"><img src="BSQ_Logo.jpg" width="61"  height="36"></td>
```

You should not use inline HTML (e.g. `width=`, `height=`, `valign=`). This should be done with CSS in a stylesheet or within a `<style>` element.

---

There is not much more to say about this script. You are now using functions. I suggest to take a look at Object Oriented Programming (OOP) if you are a little bit more familier to PHP.